# How the function get the 'x' value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody explain the flow of the code? I need to know how the function 'isEven' gets the 'x' value

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var array = [1,2,3,4,5];

    function isEven(x){ //checks if a value is even
        console.log(x)
       return x % 2 == 0; 
    }

    var newArray = array.filter(isEven); //uses a callback to check if an element is even

    console.log(newArray);
});
```

Comment: Please go through the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Here, `x` is the current element processed by the array.

Comment: @HassanImam,  An extra `]` at the end of your link and so it says 'not found'

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed the link is working at my machine.

Comment: thanks buddy. Even we wont pass any argument in the isEven function it will take the this. Am i right.

Comment: Yes, because it's the filter function passing the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comment in your code, you are passing a `callback`, so here the current `item` processed in **[`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** will be automatically passed to this `callback` function, or in other words `isEven` function will be called with the current item from `.find()` call.

As you can see in the **[MDN Reference for `.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Parameters)**:

> **callback**
>
> Function to execute on each value in the array, taking three
>   arguments:
>
> - **element** The current element being processed in the array.

So writing:

```
array.filter(isEven);
```

Is equivalent to writing:

```
array.filter(function(item){
    isEven(item);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is in this line

```
var newArray = array.filter(isEven); //uses a callback to check if an element is even
```

Here you are calling the method "filter" on the array. Filter takes a method that returns true or false, and calls it on each of the array element, passing the element itself. That line could be implemented like this

```
 let newArray;
   for(let x: array){
       if(isEven(x)){
           newArray.push(x);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `filter()` function on an array takes a function as it's input. In this case that input function is the `isEven` function. The `filter` function then iterates over the array and runs the `isEven` function over each of the elements. It then filters out any elements in the array for which the function returned `false`.

Note that in the parentheses of the `filter` function you do not specify any arguments to the `isEven` function. That is because `filter` does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
var newArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].filter(x => x % 2 == 0);
```

The `x` value is taken in your first array. See the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0):

array.filter will automatically take `this` as its argument if not passed, when it is getting looped. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more details.

So, in case of your array `this` values corresponds to the elements `1,2,3,4,5`

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to filter, it will be used as the
>   callback's this value.  Otherwise, the value undefined will be used as
>   its this value. The this value ultimately observable by callback is
>   determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen
>   by a function.

Comment: Is this correct?  I don't believe `thisArg` is used here at all, the function is using the `element` parameter, no `thisArg` is passed in. The documentation shows `filter`'s paramters as: `arr.filter(callback(element[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])`

Comment: @OliverRadini, Yes correct, `this` will be taken as element in the case of `undefined`

Comment: @mbharanidharan88 sure; which is fine, but in the code above, `this` isn't used at all, so it doesn't have any impact on the way the code works

Comment: @mbharanidharan88 ok, great; I'm sure it's useful to understand how `this` works in the context of `filter`, but I'm not seeing how it relates to this question, as the code doesn't use `this`

Answer (score 0):

**filter** is a function defined in the Array API, it receives as a parameter a "**this**" which in your case is the variable "**array**" and a callback that would be "**isEven**", inside that "this" is the values of your array, it just need to go through it and call each one to your function.

[Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter)

Comment: Is `this` used? I believe the function takes in the `element` parameter, not `this`

Comment: I do not say that, the "THIS" of the context within the Array.filter function becomes its "array" variable